# Is there a way to specify a git branch in a path dependency in the Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust-cargo

Let's say I have checked out a git repository locally and I would like to add a specific branch/tag as a dependency to a `Cargo.toml` of a rust codebase. Is there a way to do it?

I've already tried the following without success:

```ini
dep = { path = "../path/to/git/repo", branch = "hello-world" }
dep = { path = "../path/to/git/repo", rev = "12345" }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `branch` if your git dependency specifies a remote server. If it does, then this works

```ini
# Cargo.toml
dep = { git = "https://<path_to_remove_git_repo>.git", branch = "hello-world" }
```

If you use `path` to specify a dependency, the code on your local machine will be read, so it would depend on which branch was checked out (loaded) on your local machine.

Comment: For the options when specifying a git dependency see: See https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/126#issuecomment-48101852

Answer (score 0):

`path` is for [path dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-path-dependencies). You should use `git` with an absolute path for local [git dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories):

```ini
# Cargo.toml
dep = { git = "file:///absolute/path/to/git/repo", rev = "12345" }
```